# How to display data in tabular format on a txt file

Tags: python, file, tabular

I have been stuck on this python problem for hours. I'm trying to figure out how to write the data that can be manually entered above into a txt file in a way that it shows up in a two row eight column table. The contents in name_array are supposed to be headers and the  contents in data_array are the actual data pieces.

```
name = str(raw_input( "Enter the student's name: "))
medianScore = float(raw_input("Enter the median group score for quizzes:"))
indScore = float(raw_input("Enter the score of the individual quiz:  "))
assignmentScore = float(raw_input("Enter the score of the assignment: "))
test1Score = float(raw_input("Enter the score of exam one: "))
test2Score = float(raw_input("Enter the score of exam two: "))
test3Score = float(raw_input("Enter the score of the final exam: "))
fileName = str(raw_input("Enter the name of the file you would like to create: "))
f = file(fileName + ".txt" , a)

finalScore = ((medianScore * .14) + (indScore * .14) + (assignmentScore * .12) + (test1Score * .15) +(test2Score * .20) + (test3Score * .25))
data_array = [name, finalScore, test3Score, test1Score, test2Score, assignmentScore,  indScore, medianScore]
name_array = [ "Student", "Final Grade", "Final Exam", "Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Assignments", "Solo Quizzes", "Group Quizzes"]
```

Comment: you may want to fix the `a` option in `file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply output a csv-like file you can use the `csv` package:

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerow(name_array)
writer.writerow(data_array)
```

It will output:

```
Student Final Grade Final Exam  Exam 1  Exam 2  Assignments Solo Quizzes    Group Quizzes
asd 3.88    6   4   5   3   2   1
```

In this example use `tab`s as separator, but you can cange it with any char you want. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for more options.

---

Instead if you want something more human-readable you can use intead the `tabulate` package:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

f.write(tabulate([data_array], headers=name_array))
```

It will produce:

```
Student      Final Grade    Final Exam    Exam 1    Exam 2    Assignments    Solo Quizzes    Group Quizzes
---------  -------------  ------------  --------  --------  -------------  --------------  ---------------
asd                 3.88             6         4         5              3               2                1
```

See [this documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) for more options to format your table.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a ton! I had been stuck on this forever.

Comment: which of the two solutions did you pick?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like:

```
output_file = 'out.txt'
with open(output_file, 'r+') as file:
    file.write('\t'.join(name_array) + '\n')
    file.write('\t'.join(data_array) + '\n')
```

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't working. It's saying that the directory is non-existent

Comment: Try the 'x' mode in opening file